# Globally used object in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'd like to instantiate a class when I start the application and then use that object in every class (custom `ValidationAttribute`s, controllers, etc).

Where should I instantiate that class to have access to it everywhere?

I'm using ASP.NET MVC with C#.

Comment: You should be aware that if you make this object truly global, it is shared between all users of the application.  So if you modify its state, you will have a lot of problems with concurrency.  If it will be a "read only" object, then you will be ok.

Comment: Yes, I'm fully aware, that object acts like a mini database for me. I hope I managed to make it fully thread-safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make it a static property of the MvcApplication class (global.asax), and instantiate it in Application_Start.

Comment: Is there any other option that doesn't involve `static`?

Comment: If you're looking to reuse a single instance across other classes, static is the only way to go. I'm not sure how else you'd want to do it...

Answer (score 4):

Besides the choices already given, you can use dependency injector to control the management and lifetime of expensive objects. [Castle Windsor](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=MainPage&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1), [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) and [StructureMap](http://docs.structuremap.net/) play well with asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 3):

I place such object instances in the HttpRuntime Cache.

```
public static MyCacheHelper
{
    public static MyType GetMyInstance
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpRuntime.Cache[MY_CACHE_KEY] == null)
            {
                HttpRuntime.Cache[MY_CACHE_KEY] = new MyType();
            }
            return (MyType)HttpRuntime.Cache[MY_CACHE_KEY];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are wanting to create a Singleton class.  [This article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) has many examples of how to achieve this, and their caveats.  From the article, this is probably the simplest way to create a singleton:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
    // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
    static Singleton()
    {
    }

    private Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Anywhere in your code you need to access your class, you would write `Singleton.Instance.MyMethod()` (following the above example), much like you access `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`.  Aside of the boiler plate code included above, you can code your properties and methods as you would any other class.

Comment: Would this be shared across all users?